# how to get the Args... from a c++ tuple

Tags: c++, templates, tuples

I have a template class that accepts variadic template argument.

```
template <typename... Args>
class Element
{
public:
    typedef std::tuple<Args...> Tuple;

    Element(const Args&... args)
         : mArgs(args...)
    {
    }

    Tuple mArgs;
};
```

Is it possible to get the Args... from a tuple and how?

So I to be able to use the same constructor for case like this:

```
Element<Foo, Bar> element1(foo, bar);
Element<Foo, Bar> element2( magic(element1.mArgs) );
```

Comment: Have a look at std::tie but you must know what types the parameters are.

Comment: It seems you want `Element(const Tuple& t) : mArgs(t) {}`.

Comment: Yes, the second constructor will do. Unfortunately, this is a base class and providing the second constructor will be needed from many places, ... that I hope to find a way to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a copy constructor that does exactly what you want?

Note that the compiler generated copy constructor already allows this:

```
Element<Foo, Bar> element2(element1);
```

Comment: the real class is way more complicated, of course, I can create constructor from the tuple, what I will probably do if what I am asking for is impossible

Comment: You can write a copy constructor yourself so that you first call the constructor on the Args... And then invoke a copy. The temporary will most likely be elided so no harm there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no way to do *exactly* what you want. For this, you would need `magic` to return parameter pack. However, parameter packs may only appear in the context of variadic templates. So you would need to make some variadic template wrapper to provide the pack, which is not what you are looking for.

However, there is a chance that we have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. Thus, I suggest you to provide more details so we can try to solve the original problem.

Comment: this is the original class: https://github.com/ggeorgiev/dbs/blob/master/src/task/element.hpp

I need to create method rerun, that should initialize a task with the same input, and run it again

Comment: From what I can see, just copying the tuple, as rubenvb suggested, looks good.